# Python interpreter in browser. Using external modules in Skulpt

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

I can't import any modules into Sculpt. For example, I'm trying to add a numpy module:

```
Sk.externalLibraries = {
    numpy: {
          path: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/waywaaard/skulpt_numpy/master/numpy/__init__.js'
    },
    'numpy.random': {
         path: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/waywaaard/skulpt_numpy/master/numpy/random/__init__.js'
    }
};
```

But when I type `import numpy` in the browser, sculpt writes: `there is No module named numpy`

I need to add several modules: `numpy, matplotlib, scipy`, and `jcamp`. How can I do this?

Recently I've read, that Sk.externalLibraries are not supported more. But I didn't found the replacement of this construction. 
I don't know JS enough, but I need to add external libs in Sculpt. Please, help!

Comment: You should read this thread, it's about the same problem: https://github.com/skulpt/skulpt/issues/855

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'./numpy/__init__.js': {
      path: '/skulpt-numpy/dist/numpy/__init__.js'
},
'numpy.random': {
     path: '/skulpt-numpy/dist/numpy/random/__init__.js'
}
```